# After install OS X El Capitan, Apache not working

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, osx-elcapitan

I just installed in my MacBook pro "El capitan" and I can't type any host set it in vhost. Everything was working perfectly before in Yosemite. When I type one of my virtualhost I get:

> 403 "Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server."

What did I try ?

go to `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`
and uncoment this lines:

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

LoadModule vhost_alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_vhost_alias.so
```

`/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` is the same file that was working before in Yosemite since long time ago, so I haven't modified.

To install everything in Yosemite I used homebrew.

Another problem related with "El capitan", before I was able to type `http://localhost/~myuser/` and I could access to any folder in `/Users/myuser/Sites` now I get this message: `404 not found`.

I hope some help, I am not specialist in servers and it's really difficult to me to set it up, and is very annoying to waste a lot of time anytime there is a new upgrade in the OS.

Answer (score 25):

The upgrade process keeps a copy of your old `httpd.conf`. Unless you were way out of date, just overwrite the new file with your old one. Keep a copy of the new just in case...

```
sudo cp /etc/apache2/httpd.conf /etc/apache2/httpd.conf.after-update
sudo mv /etc/apache2/httpd.conf.pre-update /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
sudo apachectl restart
```

Comment: Made my day! :3

Answer (score 23):

I had the same trouble.
Type this command line you will have the error from apache :

```
apachectl configtest
```

If you have this error :

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 20 of /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-mpm.conf: Invalid command 'LockFile', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration.
```

so this link can help : https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/211015/el-capitan-apache-error-message-ah00526

Comment: `apachectl configtest` helps if DocumentRoot does not exist (This could cause Permission message).

Answer (score 11):

I experienced that after the upgrade to El Capitan the line

```
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
```

in

```
/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

was commented again. After uncommenting it and restarting apache, everything worked alright again.

Comment: In addition to above, I did a diff-merge on `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf~previous` to restore my pre-upgrade settings.

Comment: I also faced the exactly same problem. I have uncommented the line and restarted the apache but still the problem is not resolved.

Comment: @abhishek, this solved my problem: http://tomjbward.co.uk/symfony-on-osx-el-capitan/ . I did just the Step 2.

Comment: I needed to uncomment LoadModule userdir_module libexec/apache2/mod_userdir.so

Comment: doing the diff as proposed by @Justin worked for me :)

Comment: I uncommented the thing and also replaced my httpd.conf with the ~previous one, it worked!

Comment: Thanks @janwo! Made my day :)

Answer (score 3):

I have merged to two versions (`httpd.conf` and `http.conf~previous`) and after that I discovered that the v-host wasn't working anymore. 
After disabling rule 19 `#NameVirtualHost *:80` in `/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` everything worked again!

Comment: Thanks JVD! Worked like a charm. I was getting a Forbidden 'til I did this.  I believe (in the end) it was my DocumentRoot setting.

Answer (score 2):

LockFile is a directive of Apache ≤ 2.2. El Capitan comes with Apache version 2.4. so, you need to disable LockFile

First, just to be sure apache is stopped:

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

Then edit your `httpd-mpm.conf:`

Comment this lines

```
#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
<IfModule !mpm_winnt_module>
<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
  LockFile "/private/var/log/apache2/accept.lock"
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Start apache `sudo apachectl start` and that's all

Answer (score 0):

As some have mentioned the problem is that the upgrade to El Capitan backed up your previous httpd.conf and renamed it httpd.conf~previous and gave you a new httpd.conf.  What you need to do though with these files to fix your problem is:

Use nano or other editor to open httpd.conf~previous and look for these 2 lines:

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/my-machine-name/Prev-Localhost-Path
<Directory "/Users/my-machine-name/Prev-Localhost_path">
```

Copy them and then using nano open httpd.conf and look for these 2 lines:

```
DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
```

Comment them out by entering the '#' character in front of each one, and then below them paste in the two lines you copied from your original file. Save the file and exit.

After that you'll need to reboot.  My setup would not work until I made these changes and then rebooted.  But perhaps the suggestion by DSG to restart apache will suffice:

```
sudo apachectl restart
```